# Error using Jackson and Json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to parse some JSON  (full example of the JSON can be seen in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/306ffbf0cc1ea6c7ee30/raw/7a017a56e1f20466d8b04cfab1ce0ddf4b176f02/library.json)). I show the general structure of the JSON below:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Principles of Compiler Design",
        "authors": [
            "Aho",
            "Ullman"
        ],
        "publisher": "Addison Wesley",
        "year": 1977
    },
    {
        "title": "Compilers: Principles Techniques and Tools",
        "authors": [
            "Aho",
            "Sethi",
            "Ullman"
        ],
        "publisher": "Addison Wesley",
        "year": 1985
    }
]
```

I am trying to parse the JSON with Jackson libraries, but I get the following error while testing:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: library.json; line: 2, column: 49] (through reference chain: com.acme.datatypes.User["authors"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:588)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JdkDeserializers$StringDeserializer.deserialize(JdkDeserializers.java:90)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JdkDeserializers$StringDeserializer.deserialize(JdkDeserializers.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:336)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:89)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:290)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:112)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2563)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1759)
    at com.acme.datatypes.UserTest.main(UserTest.java:20)
```

Here is my code:

User Test class:

```
public class UserTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException,
            JsonMappingException, IOException {
        File jsonFile = new File("library.json");

        User user = null;

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        user = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, User.class);
        System.out.println(user.getTitle());

        user = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, User.class);
        System.out.println(user.getAuthors());

        user = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, User.class);
        System.out.println(user.getPublisher());

        user = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, User.class);
        System.out.println(user.getYear());
    }
}
```

User class:

```
public class User {

    private String authors;
    private String publisher;
    private String title;
    private Number year;

    public String getAuthors() {
        return this.authors;
    }

    public void setAuthors(String authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return this.publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Number getYear() {
        return this.year;
    }

    public void setYear(Number year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Thanks.

Comment: can you share the java code also, you need to convert this to a list

Comment: How did you declare your `authors` property? It should be a collection or array type.

Comment: @Arun P Johny , I have edited the the document and added the code for you to see

Comment: @Perception , can you please look at the code and tell me where to edit it?

Comment: @tribick - Your `authors` property cannot be a string because in JSON it is an array. Change its type to `List<String>`.

Comment: @ Perception, i am getting this error now: Can not deserialize instance of com.acme.datatypes.User out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: library.json; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: @tribrick - to save time I've posted an answer below. Take a look at it and see if it helps you.

Comment: @Perception  im getting this error after following what you told to do : Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input within/between ARRAY entries
 at [Source: library.json; line: 11, column: 200]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two quick things:

1. Your User class is defining the `authors` property as a String. But in JSON its an array, so you need to use a collections or array type in your Java object. Something like:

   `private List<String> authors`
2. You repeatedly parse the JSON file in your test class. You only need to parse it once, and you need to use a supertype token, since there is a list of items in the JSON (not just one). You are also using the wrong type to deserialize (User.class). Instead of all these lines:

   `user = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, User.class);`
   `System.out.println(user.getTitle());`

   `user = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, User.class); // <-- unnecessary parsing
   System.out.println(user.getAuthors());`

   `user = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, User.class); // <-- unnecessary parsing
   System.out.println(user.getPublisher());`

   `user = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, User.class); // <-- unnecessary parsing
   System.out.println(user.getYear());`

Just use:

```
List<User> userList =
    mapper.readValue(jsonFile, new TypeReference<List<User>>() {});
```

Once you get a list of users in your test class you can iterate them using an enhanced for loop.

```
for(User user : userList) {
    System.out.println(user.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: it is clear but im getting this error now: Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input within/between ARRAY entries
 at [Source: library.json; line: 11, column: 200]

Comment: @tribrick - dump the contents of your JSON file into [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com), and validate that it is well-formed.

Comment: What version of Jackson are you using? Also, you might want to verify that you have no "" or [] values for the array element of your JSON (though technically, [] is perfectly valid).

Comment: jackson-annotations-2.0.1, jackson-core-2.0.1, jackson-databind-2.0.1

Comment: @tribrick - You can browse through [this working example](https://github.com/sevenhillsoftware/bookreader). If you know Git and Maven you can download and run it as well.

Comment: @tribrick - if this answer helped you, feel free to upvote/accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are working with an array, you need to convert it into an array or a list

As Array

```
MyClass[] myObjects = mapper.readValue(json, MyClass[].class);
```

As List

```
List<MyClass> myObjects = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>(){});
```

User

```
public class User {

    private List<String> authors;
    private String publisher;
    private String title;
    private Number year;

    public List<String> getAuthors() {
        return this.authors;
    }

    public void setAuthors(List<String> authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return this.publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Number getYear() {
        return this.year;
    }

    public void setYear(Number year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<User> l = mapper.readValue(new File(""),new TypeReference<List<User>>() {});
```