# How i can recover a Map of objects from json?

Tags: java, json, jsonserializer, serialization

I have this class

```
public static class SomeClass {
    public SomeClass(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    private final String field;

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```

I have also this test (**edited**)

```
@Test
public void testStringifyMapOfObjects() {
    Map<String, SomeClass> original = Maps.newTreeMap();
    original.put("first", new SomeClass("a"));
    original.put("second", new SomeClass("b"));
    String encoded = JsonUtil.toJson(original);
    Map<String, SomeClass> actual = JsonUtil.fromJson(encoded, Map.class);
    Assert.assertEquals("{'first':{'field':'a'},'second':{'field':'b'}}", encoded.replaceAll("\\s", "").replaceAll("\"", "'"));
    Assert.assertEquals(original.get("first"), actual.get("first"));
}
```

The test fails with

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.facade.transport.test.TestToolTest$SomeClass@6e3ed98c> but was:<{field=a}>
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:277)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:64)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:71)
    at eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.facade.transport.test.TestToolTest.testStringifyMapOfObjects(TestToolTest.java:90)
```

Can I make json to properly serialize objects as the values of the map or should I use something else?

**edited**

```
public class JsonUtil {
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonUtil.class);

    public static <T> String toJson(T data) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.warn("can't format a json object from [" + data + "]", e);
            return null;
        }
        //
        // return Json.stringify(Json.toJson(data));
    }

    public static <T> T fromJson(String description, Class<T> theClass) {
        try {
            JsonNode parse = new ObjectMapper().readValue(description, JsonNode.class);
            T fromJson = new ObjectMapper().treeToValue(parse, theClass);
            return fromJson;
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // throw new RuntimeException("can't parse a json object of type " + theClass.getName() + " from [" + description + "]", e);
            LOG.warn("can't parse a json object from [" + description + "]", e);
            return null;
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // throw new RuntimeException("can't parse a json object of type " + theClass.getName() + " from [" + description + "]", e);
            LOG.warn("can't parse a json object from [" + description + "]", e);
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // throw new RuntimeException("can't parse a json object of type " + theClass.getName() + " from [" + description + "]", e);
            LOG.warn("can't parse a json object from [" + description + "]", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What library are you using there?

Comment: I have dependencies on
org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.9 and jackson-core-asl:1.9.9

Comment: The `Json` class is not part of any version of Jackson I know. Is that custom code? If so, include it in your question please.

Comment: Thank you @Perception for your help. I added the utility class. I didn't realized that is my class and not in the library. I also edited the test that still fails. Else I managed to solve my problem by adding the container class. I still don't know exactly why didn't worked like in my first test. Still I have a workaround :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into a problem related to Java generics. To summarize, when deserializing data into a non-reifiable type (aka a type for which actual type information is not available at runtime) you need to use a *supertype token*. You can get more detail about what a supertype token is (and why you need to use one) by reading these SO posts:

- [Pass parameterized type to method as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15595882/680925)
- [Error using Jackson and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15254970/680925)
- [Deserialize JSON to ArrayList using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9829502/680925)

And also from the Jackson documentation:

- [Data Binding With Generics](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Data_Binding_with_Generics)
- [TypeReference Javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html)

*The basic problem is that when you use a typical generic object, the actual type parameters for the object aren't available at runtime. Therefore Jackson doesn't know which actual class to instantiate and deserialize your data into*.

The easiest way to get around the problem would be adding an overload to your JSON utility class, that accepts a type reference (as opposed to a `Class<T>`). For example:

```
public static <T> T fromJson(String json, TypeReference<T> typeRef) {
     if(json == null || typeRef == null) return null;

     return new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, typeRef);
}
```

To be used as such:

```
Map<String, SomeClass> actual = JsonUtil.fromJson(
    encoded,
    new TypeReference<Map<String, SomeClass>>(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the simplest solution is to create a "container" class that will contain the  map. This is working probably because the container has enough type details for the map, as opposed to the case when a map is used directly.

```
public static class SomeClass {
    private final String field;

    private SomeClass() {
        this("wrong");
    }
    public SomeClass(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SomeClass[" + field + "]";
    }
}

public static class SomeClassContainer {
    private final Map<String, SomeClass> all = Maps.newTreeMap();

    public Map<String, SomeClass> getAll() {
        return all;
    }
}
```

After this ... the updated test is

```
@Test
public void testStringifyMapOfObjects() {
    SomeClassContainer original = new SomeClassContainer();
    original.getAll().put("first", new SomeClass("a"));
    original.getAll().put("second", new SomeClass("b"));
    String encoded = JsonUtil.toJson(original);
    System.out.println(encoded);
    SomeClassContainer actual = JsonUtil.fromJson(encoded, SomeClassContainer.class);
    System.out.println(ObjectUtils.toString(actual));
    Assert.assertEquals("{'all':{'first':{'field':'a'},'second':{'field':'b'}}}", encoded.replaceAll("\\s", "").replaceAll("[\"]", "'"));
    Assert.assertEquals("class eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.facade.transport.test.TestToolTest$SomeClass", actual.getAll().get("first").getClass().toString());
    Assert.assertEquals(original.getAll().get("first").toString(), actual.getAll().get("first").toString());
    Assert.assertEquals(original.getAll().get("second").toString(), actual.getAll().get("second").toString());
}
```