# Can't understand JsonMappingException

Tags: java, json, mapping

When running the following line:

```
Request<Map<String, Object>> requestMap = JsonUtils.fromJson(eventContext.getMessage().getPayloadAsString(), Request.class);
```

I got this Java exception:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class ***.objectmodel.Request] from JSON floating-point number; no one-double/Double-arg constructor/factory method
```

Comment: What's the JSON?

Comment: And what's in Request.class.  The error message means the JSON parser has encountered a value it thinks is a floating point number, like 3.14. It is trying to map the floating point value into the parse result, but can not find a "one double arg" constructor or factory method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem while debugging.
The JSON string was actually not a JSON (particulary only an ip address string "192.168.1.1". So it was not a deserialization mapping issue with the target class (as I supposed initially).

Moral of the fable: The exception is too complicated. A "Not a JSON string" would have been enough.

Comment: How would any XXXX parser know "not valid XXXX syntax" before it finishes parsing the whole "XXXX formatted" text?  Parsers generally work one token at a time from left to right.  The best error it can give you is as much detail as possible about exactly where it blew up.

Comment: You are right, but at least it could use a more accurate name in the exception like "JsonSyntaxException" . (this exception actually exists for Google JSON library).

Answer (score 1):

It looks, for me, that you are trying to turn the *String* (JSON) into a Request, but you are not specifying which kind of Request (generic parameters) you are trying to parse.

I would try to extract that JSON into a *Map* like this:

```
Map<String, Object> actual = JsonUtil.fromJson(encoded, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
```

Once you are receiving a JSON and wants to deserialize it, I believe it have information and you must create a specific entity to map it, then it would be like this:

```
Map<String, YourEntity> actual = JsonUtil.fromJson(encoded, new TypeReference<Map<String, YourEntity>>(){});
```

More details about this solution you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609266/how-i-can-recover-a-map-of-objects-from-json?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: Well It was a really good approach in case it was a deserialization mapping issue with the target class.  I posted the "solution" in my answer below. Thanks for the snippet anyway, it can be helpful.

Comment: In any case I believe you could bring your exception to the maintainers of this library as an issue. That exception It not meaningful at Allan...